# Terminal emulator with flexible editing and rerunning, like Kibana dev tools

Tags: terminal-emulator

I'm imagining an interface like Kibana dev tools for Elasticsearch, where there's an editor window on the left (which you can click around and make changes freely), and next to each code block on the left there's a run button, which runs the command (/ request) and shows the results in a pane on the right.

Many of the individual features that are desirable in this appear in lots of terminal emulators. For example, some allow you to edit commands in a natural way (including using a mouse), and some automatically keep a list of old commands in a pane. I imagine some might save the results of every command somewhere for revisiting later. However, the flow of having a single command entry point is ultimately inflexible, and I tend to work by writing scripts in an editor and then calling them from the terminal instead. This has its own problems because it inhibits one's ability to jump around between commands.

I feel like the Kibana dev tools interface would be very flexible and user-friendly way of working in a terminal environment. It could keep a history of commands run, along with their output, and you could use the editor window as a general paste-space along with your commands as you work on them. If you're building up a script, then you could do it piece by piece until you're ready to put the whole thing together.

Does something like this exist? If not, does anyone think it would be useful?